# Setting a relative column width in XAML. '0.5*' string cannot be converted to Length

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, width

Here's the XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lstGames" Background="#343434" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="0.5*"/> //<-----------HERE!
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Title:" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Release Date:" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}" />
                    </StackPanel>                            
                </StackPanel>  
            </Grid>                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
</ListBox>
```

All I want is for the first column to at most be around 35% of the total width of the window. I was under the impression that this notation was allowed, but something is wrong and I'm getting that exception fired.

Any suggestions?

If I change it to only `Width="0.5*"` then it compiles and runs, but still doesn't give the pictures (the columns) a uniform width:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth` is a double, not a `GridLength`. So it can't be a relative value. However, since it's a dependency property, you might be able to bind it to the total width of the window, using a converter with a parameter.